# HTML5 form validation before click event

Tags: jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have the following form and input button:

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="category_markups_form" data-toggle="validator">
    {{#each context.category_0}}
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputType" class="col-md-2 control-label" data-error="Please enter a number.">{{category_name}}</label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="number" min="1.0" class="form-control" name="{{category_name}}" data-error="Please enter a number." required>
        </div>
      </div>
      {{/each}}
      <input id="to_subcategory_markups" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Next: Subcategory Markups">
  </form>
```

My input button validates all of the inputs to make sure they are valid. My button also calls a script to show another form if it is clicked:

```
$("#to_subcategory_markups").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#subcategory_markups").show();
});
```

My problem is, as written, my other form will show if I click the input submit button WITHOUT validating all the inputs. The only way to make sure the form validates is by removing my input's `id` attribute. But this means my click event would not fire. Is there a way I can make my form validate before firing off the click event?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You should listen for the `submit` event on the form. Then the HTML5 validators will stop the submit if there are validation errors.

```
$(".form-horizontal").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#subcategory_markups").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

please use this syntax to validate your form

```
$("#f").validate({
            rules: {
                field01: {
                    required: true
                },
                field02:{
                    required: true,
                },
                field03: {
                    required: true
                },
                field04: {
                    required: true,
                },
                field05: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                 form.submit(); //  or your action
             }
  });
```

here is f is your form id and field0* will be the name of your input fields that you want to be required.